`post_updated_messages` filter
I am learning Plugin development. I am working on post_updated_messages filter.
How can I get an array key like popup in this array ?


The function you attach as a filter needs to take in a variable as an argument and return that variable once it's done processing whatever it is you need it to do. For example:
function wpse426272_messages( $messages ) {

  $messages['game'] = array( 'Game updated', 'Game published', 'etc' );
      
  return $messages;
}

add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'wpse426272_messages' );


Thanks @Chris Cox. Actually I would like to create an index like below.
[game] => Array
    (
        [1] => Game updated.
        [4] => Game updated.
        [6] => Game published.
        [7] => Game saved.
        [8] => Game submitted.
    )


Updated the example.
